# Push a new view controller on tableview cell tap

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have one header file which is

```
@interface DemoFirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

In the source file of this header file i have declare this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AnotherViewController *anotherViewController=[[AnotherViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath: row=%d", indexPath.row);

}
```

and anotherViewController file is

```
@interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *message;
}

@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *message;

@end
```

I am doing this all using Xib file. not storyboard.

This is `tabbased Application`. and two viewcontroller are already declared in Appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[DemoFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[DemoSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

bt on tapping of table cell, anotherViewcontroller is not comming. Plz reply as soon as possible.

Comment: is your NSLog for didSelectRowAtIndexPath working?

Comment: Have you properly set your `DemoFirstViewController` with `Navigation`controller's `initWithRootViewController`method in `AppDelegate`??
Or

Have you implemented `initWithNibName` method in your `AnotherView`??

Comment: @Zeel - See my edited answer now ~~

Answer (score 1):

There may be few reasons behind this:

1. `UINavigationController` should be correctly implemented in `Appdelegate` class.
2. `UITableView` should not be add on any `subView` of `self.view`.
3. If `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is being called it is okay other wise You have forgotten to set `tableView` delegates.

   ```
   tableView.delegate = self;
   ```

**EDIT:** I read [Zeel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1868637/zeel)'s comment he said he is using `TabBar` and he didn't mention it before So I'm editing my answer:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    DemoFirstViewController *viewController1 = [[DemoFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav1 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    DemoSecondViewController *viewController2 = [[DemoSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav2 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[nav1, nav2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: +1. This pretty much sums up all the rookie mistakes when pushing a view controller from a tableview.

Comment: I don't understand the second point. AFAIK UITableView can be a subview of the main view without any risk, if you use an UIViewController instead of an UITableViewController (like in this case)

Comment: @LombaX - `UITableView can be a subview of the main view` Yes I agree but should not be a `subView` of a `View` which is also a `subView` of main view ..... I mean `tableView` should be add on `self.View`.

Comment: Uhm...ok, I didn't know :-) I'll search because it seems "interesting" :-) if you have some indication/link explaining why i'll be thankful!

Comment: I have this just because experience, at once when I was trying to push a view by didSelectRow: then I got this reason and I want that others dont waste their time on same reason :)

Comment: I added this above code in appDelegate but then also after pressing table cell my app is terminated with following exception :

Comment: 2013-01-08  TabBarNavBarDemo[841:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "AnotherViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1c91deb 0xf7f18 0xf8418 0xf8648 0xf8882 0xf8b2a 0x10fef5 0x10ffdb 0x110286 0x110381 0x110eab 0x1114a3 0x111098 0x3004 0xc68d5 0xc6b3d 0xacde83 0x1c51376 0x1c50e06 0x1c38a82 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1bec7e3 0x1bec668 0x1765c 0x1f4d 0x1e75)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Hmmm it is because you took a new `xib` for `ViewController` class and didn't set its view in `XIB`. Open `XIB` select `File's Owner` set its class to your `ViewController` class. Now right click on `File's Owner` attach its view to `XIB` view by drag and dropping.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Navigation Controller: %@", self.navigationController);
```

Check what is printed by this line.
I suspect you have forgotten to add the navigationController in your hierarchy

UPDATE:
Basing on your AppDelegate code, update it like this to solve your problem:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[DemoFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoFirstViewController" bundle:nil];

    // here I create a Navigation Controller and set its root view controller to viewController1
    UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[DemoSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // updated this line to show the navController1 (which contains viewController1)
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

If even viewController2 is an UITableViewController that needs to push something, do the same thing on it (add another UINavigationController, set the root viewcontroller, and set ad a viewController of the TabBarController)

Comment: Means the AnotherViewController should be subclass of UINavigationController? and in the xib of this file i have to drag and drop navigationcontroller from Objects?

Comment: No, you have only to add a Navigation Controller to your controller hierarchy. I see that you added your AppDelegate code, I update my answer and show you what to change

Comment: Thanks to all for giving reply. But when i press on table cell after adding above code on appDelegate my app is terminated with following exception.... >>>>>>>

Comment: TabBarNavBarDemo[799:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "AnotherViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1c91deb 0xf7f18 0xf8418 0xf8648 0xf8882 0xf8b2a 0x10fef5 0x10ffdb 0x110286 0x110381 0x110eab 0x1114a3 0x111098 0x3004 0xc68d5 0xc6b3d 0xacde83 0x1c51376 0x1c50e06 0x1c38a82 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1bec7e3 0x1bec668 0x1765c 0x1f4d 0x1e75)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: Have you changed anything in your AnotherViewController nib? Check that the "view" outlet from File Owner to the main view is connected. Click on the nib -> right click on the "File Owner" -> drag the "view" outlet on the root view of the nib file.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are pointing in the right direction. Just in case you still haven't gotten hold of it, check if you have added the following piece of code in your `appdelegate`,

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

and check again.

Comment: I have made tabbed application so there are already declared 2 view controller.

Comment: @Zeel - Why didn't you mention this in your question .... this is very important cause ? Please edit your question and make it as clear as possible for getting a suitable answer.